# Remove previews from dropzone after success without page refresh

Tags: jquery, dropzone

I have a page where the dropzone uploaded is called inside a modal. The modal is called depending on the different preview parameters passed from a list. After the file is uploaded the preview of the dropzone div needs to be cleared on modal dismiss without page refresh.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above is attained by adding the following two lines in the button click event inside the jquery code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
        $("#SaveAndEmail").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ///Add your code for saving
            $('.dz-preview').empty();
            $('.dz-message').show();      
        });
    });
</script>
```